# How to open port 2195 in iptables centos cpanel 11

Tags: cpanel, iptables, centos5

Please help me. how to add 2195 port in iptables ...centos server and cpanel 11 installed.

Answer (score 3):

If you have root password and can login through ssh run these:

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 2195 -j ACCEPT
/etc/init.d/iptables stop
/etc/init.d/iptables start
```